# How to measure CPU time in java virtual threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-threads

In java, to measure CPU time used for a thread, one usually does something like:

```
var cpuTimeStart = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean().getCurrentThreadCpuTime();
//Some lengthy operation
var totalCPU = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean().getCurrentThreadCpuTime() - cpuTimeStart;
```

This works fine. But since the introduction of virtual threads (JDK 21), this method only works for platform threads, not for virtual threads.

So this always reports 0:

```
var vThread = Thread.ofVirtual().start(() -> {
  var cpuTimeStart = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean().getCurrentThreadCpuTime();
  //Some lengthy operation
  var totalCPU = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean().getCurrentThreadCpuTime() - cpuTimeStart;
  //totalCPU is always 0
});
vThread.join();
```

So, the question is how are we supposed to measure CPU times with the introduction of virtual threads?

Answer (score 1):

> So, the question is how are we supposed to measure CPU times with the introduction of virtual threads?

I don't think it is possible.

Why? Because to measure virtual thread CPU time, the runtime would need to make syscalls to find and record the current (non-virtual) thread's CPU time ... *each time there is a virtual thread switch*. The overhead of those syscalls would (largely) defeat to point of implementing virtual threads in the first place.

Comment: I understand it may be desirable for extremely short operations, but real world is... more complex. Consider VirtualThreadExecutor in tomcat, if someone enables it, it will be impossible to profile it. I wonder how profilers can possibly work around that (ex: https://github.com/newrelic/newrelic-java-agent/blob/6e6c4db548243b5c438f27ba9dffaf511ae204db/newrelic-agent/src/main/java/com/newrelic/agent/profile/v2/Profile.java#LL90C1-L90C1 )

Comment: I think you have missed my point.  If virtual threads *did* support CPU measurement, that would make them too slow for most use-cases where CPU measurement is not a requirements.  If you need to be able to measure thread CPU time, you shouldn't be using virtual threads.

Comment: Maybe you should ask the authors of that profiler how they intend to solve this (IMO) unsolvable problem :-)